Does the consistency depend on the consistency of ZFC?
I saw somewhere that to prove the consistency of Peano'a arithmetic (PA) we prove $\mathbb{N}$ is a model of PA and this fact has always bothered me.
Before explaining what bothers me, let me first explain what I understand from model theory and soundness theorem. Basically what I understand is that a structure for PA is $(M,\phi, +_M, \times_m,<_m)$ where $M$ is a set. First of all since we say that $M$ is a set I am guessing that we need to already have a theory such as ZFC or any other theory that describes sets. Then given an variable assignment $A$ we define the interpretation of terms $I$ inductively as follows:
$$I(M, A, c) = \phi(c) \text{ where } c \text{ is a constant.}$$
$$I(M, A, x) = A(x) \text{ where } x \text{ is a variable.}$$
$$I(M, A, t_1 + t_2) = I(M, A, t_1) +_M I(M, A, t_2)$$
And so on. Then for the truth values $V$ on formulas we also define it recursively as one would expect using these basic cases:
$$M \vDash_A t_1 = t_1 \text{ iff } ZFC \vdash I(M, A, t_1) =_{ZFC} I(M, A, t_2)$$
$$M \vDash_A t_1 < t_1 \text{ iff } ZFC \vdash(I(M, A, t_1), I(M, A, t_2)) \in <_M$$
And for negation for example one would have:
$$M \vDash \neg F \text{ iff } M \nvDash F$$
And we say that a structure $M$ of PA is a model of PA iff for every formula $F$ of PA we have $M \vDash F$.
Finally there is the following soundness theorem: If a PA has a model then it is consistent. Where being consistent means that we do not have $PA \vdash \bot$.
As I said above I saw that a way prove that PA is consistent is to prove that $\mathbb{N}$ with it's usual structure is a model for PA. So for each axiom $F$ in PA we check that $\mathbb{N} \vDash F$.
This is where I get confused. Let us consider the axiom $F := \forall x \neg(x + 1 = 0)$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ I agree that we have $ZFC \vdash \neg(n + 1 = 0)$ and thus if ZFC is consistent we cannot have $ZFC \vdash n + 1 = 0$ thus one has $\mathbb{N} \nvDash n + 1 = 0$ which leads us to $\mathbb{N} \vDash \neg(n + 1 = 0)$.
HOWEVER if ZFC is not consistent then one can prove everying, thus in particular $ZFC \vdash n + 1 = 0$ and then we get $\mathbb{N} \vDash n + 1 = 0$ and using the definition of $\vDash$ we obtain $\mathbb{N} \nvDash \neg(n + 1 = 0)$ which implies that $\mathbb{N} \nvDash \forall x \neg(x + 1 = 0)$. This means that if ZFC is not consistent then $\mathbb{N}$ is not a model for PA and we cannot conclude that PA is consistent.
I understand that we usually assume that ZFC is consistent because we cannot prove it (I heard this somewhere) but saying that we need to assume ZFC is consistent to prove that PA is seems overkill. Because if I would want to prove that PA is consistent using the consistency of ZFC I would try to use some kind of embedding from PA into ZFC inductively on the size of formulas defined as follows:
$$t_1 = t_2 \longmapsto \left( \underset{i}{\bigwedge} x_i \in \mathbb{N} \right) \rightarrow (t_1 = t_2) \text{ where } x_i \text{ are variables int } t_1, t_2$$
$$t_1 < t_2 \longmapsto \left( \underset{i}{\bigwedge} x_i \in \mathbb{N} \right) \rightarrow (t_1 < t_2) \text{ where } x_i \text{ are variables int } t_1, t_2$$
I have not thought this though deeply I believe it would be possible to define such an embedding from PA into ZFC and use that embedding to prove that any inconsistency in PA would be carried into ZFC. I would even believe that for any theory T there is a bijection between the models of T and embeddings of T into ZFC. Using the observation above I would not be surprised if the soundness theorem is equivalent to the consistency of ZFC...
If what I am saying is correct and that we need to assume the consistency of ZFC to prove the consistency of PA are there any ways to prove that PA is consistent without using ZFC? I am believe that the answer is no from computability theory.
Please keep in mind that I am no specialist in logic so if possible please keep your answers in a rather elementary language.

If ZFC is inconsistent, then we can also prove (from ZFC) that there are only finitely many prime numbers. Does the infinitude of primes therefore also depend on the consistency of ZFC?

You write: "This means that if ZFC is not consistent then $\mathbb{N}$ is not a model for PA and we cannot conclude that PA is consistent." This is not so. If ZFC is not consistent, then $\mathbb{N}$ is still a model of PA, and ZFC still proves this fact. If ZFC is inconsistent, it proves more things than most people currently think it does, but certainly not fewer things. People say that "the product of compact spaces is compact" because that's a theorem of ZFC (or their preferred foundation). The consistency of PA is no different: people say it since their chosen foundation proves it.

And no, we don't need to assume the consistency of ZFC to prove the consistency of PA. The consistency of PA is simply a theorem of ZFC: one does not need ZFC+Con(ZFC) to prove the consistency of PA.

When you say that if ZFC is not consistent then $\mathbb{N}$ is model for PA I disagree, I explained above why I beleive this is not the case, if my reasoning is wrong could you point out where it is not correct?

@LeGrandSpectacle If ZFC is inconsistent, ZFC proves every sentence. In particular, ZFC proves "$\mathbb{N}$ is a model of PA". Now, you're entirely correct that if ZFC is inconsistent, ZFC also proves "$\mathbb{N}$ is not a model of PA". But this doesn't change the fact that ZFC proves "$\mathbb{N}$ is a model of PA". Alternatively: We don't know whether ZFC is consistent or not. In this state of ignorance, we can prove PA is consistent. If we additionally assume (or learn) ZFC is inconsistent, then we can also prove PA is inconsistent. But the proof that PA is consistent is unconditional.

Gerhard Gentzen gave a proof of the consistency of PA back in 1936 (and I think followed this with a few other variations, so I don't know where what follows fits into the timeline). His approach is proof-theoretic and what he essentially does is give a sequence of reduction procedures on formal proofs of atomic sentences from PA. The reduction procedures can be iterated as long as the formal proofs contain non-atomic sentences and/or inference rules which are not structural (Gentzen works in a sequent calculus, so in addition to inference rules for connectives, quantifiers, and induction, there are structural rules). Proofs consisting only of atomic sentences and structural rules are called simple and Gentzen shows (1) that no simple proof is a proof of $0=1$ and (2) that iteratively applying the reduction procedures to proofs of atomic sentences eventually results in a simple proof. I think that step (1) really only uses induction and step (2) depends only on induction along $\varepsilon_0$ (a countable ordinal). None of this should depend on ZFC's consistency. In fact, Gentzen uses ordinal notations, which are defined in a combinatorial way and don't depend on the set-theoretic definition of ordinals. So if you are looking for a proof of the consistency of PA which doesn't take the consistency of ZFC as a starting assumption, you might try reading Gentzen's proof (or some modern presentation of it since the proof is a bit of a beast).

I don't think it's quite accurate to say the "$\mathbb N$ is a model" proof uses the consistency of ZFC as a starting assumption. One could say it uses the axioms of ZFC as starting assumptions (though ZFC is overkill for formalizing it).

@spaceisdarkgreen, I don't mean for my response to imply that either. I suppose I am merely trying to offer an alternative approach which the OP might find more palatable.

@spaceisdarkgreen Above I explained why I beleive that "$\mathbb{N}$ is a model" uses the consistency of ZFC, if this fact is not true could you point out the flaw in my reasoning?

@LeGrandSpectacle Whether ZFC is consistent or not is not even mentioned in the proof. You just take $\mathbb N$ and show it is a model for PA. The theory that gets mentioned is PA, not ZFC. "This is where I get confused...." indeed, you suddenly start mentioning issues such as whether ZFC proves $\lnot \forall n(n+1\ne 0)$ that are irrelevant to the matter at hand. What's relevant is whether $\mathbb N\models \forall n(n+1\ne 0)$ or not. You are confusing working in ZFC, which you may well be doing implicitly or explicitly here, with talking about ZFC.

@OldMathLogan Well, you say "which doesn't take the consistency of ZFC as a starting assumption" at the end. I don't disagree that pointing to Gentzen's proof is a good answer to skepticism that the "model" proof is using too strong assumptions to probably satisfy anyone with a thoroughly thought out doubt about the consistency of PA.

@spaceisdarkgreen But to prove that $\mathbb{N} \vDash \forall n \neg (n + 1 = 0)$ by definition of $\vDash$ you need to prove that $\mathbb{N} \vDash_A \neg(n + 1 = 0)$ for any assignment $A$. And this means by definition that you need to prove that $\mathbb{N} \nvDash_A (n + 1 = 0)$ and again by definition of $\vDash$ this means that you need to show that we do not have $ZFC \vdash (n + 1 = 0)$ for a certain $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If ZFC is inconsistent one does have $ZFC \vdash (n + 1 = 0)$. If this reasoning is correct then if ZFC is inconsistent: $\mathbb{N} \nvDash \forall \neg(n + 1 = 0)$

@LeGrandSpectacle "again by definition of ⊨ this means that you need to show that we do not have ⊢(+1=0) for a certain ∈ℕ." No it doesn't and I don't know why you insist it does. The definition of $\models$ and the preceding stuff have literally nothing to do with ZFC or what things it proves.

@spaceisdarkgreen But to speak of $\vDash$ we use the notion of models which in turn use the notion of sets, and since we are using sets I assume that we are using ZFC to describe sets. If we are not using ZFC and we suppose an intuitive notion of $\mathbb{N}$ then spending time to develop PA seems pointless in my opinion.

@LeGrandSpectacle As I said before, we may be using ZFC as our background theory when we prove this (though it's not the only possible foundation and also we don't need anything nearly so strong to formalize the ideas of this proof... e.g. some fragment of 2nd order arithmetic suffices). The proof itself, however, makes absolutely no mention of ZFC. And it goes through just fine with ZFC as the background theory... ZFC + Con(ZFC) is not needed.

@spaceisdarkgreen I am not sure that I understand your reply, for a relation symbol $R$ how would you define $M \vDash_A R(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ without using ZFC or a theory that describes the behaviour of sets?

@LeGrandSpectacle "As I said before, we may be using ZFC as our background theory when we prove this." There is a difference between using ZFC to prove things and referencing ZFC in these proofs. The proof talks about sets, not ZFC. ZFC talks about sets. You can use ZFC to do this proof. ZFC can also talk about ZFC, whether it's consistent, what it can prove, etc. This proof doesn't talk about ZFC, whether it's consistent, what it can prove, etc. It talks about $\mathbb N$, the satisfaction relation (stuff that involves sets), and PA.
